# I do not understand this part. Can anyone explain how this loop and math.random*2 is working

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, datagrid

help me to understand this code

public class Exercise12 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input a number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();
    printMatrix(n);
}
```

public static void printMatrix(int n) {

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.printin((int)(Math.random() * 2) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a number between `0.0` (inclusive) and `1.0` (exclusive).

Therefore `(Math.random() * 2)` is a number between `0.0` (inclusive) and `2.0` (exclusive).

Therefore `(int)(Math.random() * 2)` is either `0` or `1`:

- If `(Math.random() * 2) == 0.xxxx`, casting it to `int` results in `0`
- If `(Math.random() * 2) == 1.xxxx`, casting it to `int` results in `1`

Hence this code prints a matrix of n * n `0` or `1` elements.